# C# memory allocation when creating object

Tags: c#, .net

My question is what happen in memory when we create two object for one class variable.
For example:

```
class a = new class(); 
a = new class();
```

At that time, are both allocated in same memory

Answer (score 2):

Two objects are allocated on the heap. The first one is replaced by the one from the second statement, and will be deallocated by the garbage collector when there's sufficient memory pressure that necessitates a collection.

Comment: Is the memory occupied by the first one till GC run?

Comment: @JothiRaj That is basically true, yes.

Comment: @Jothi Raj As mjwills said, yes, but you don't need to worry about it. The garbage collector is smart and if it needs memory it'll go looking for dereferenced objects. That said, you shouldn't be silly and start willy-nilly creating thousands of objects all over the place that repeatedly get released. That can lead to issues like a fragmented heap. It's exceedingly rare that you'd have to worry about that either though.

Answer (score 0):

`class a = new class();`

This will create two things: an instance of the class on the heap, and a reference `a` to that instance.

`a = new class();`

This will create a new instance of the class on the heap, and change the reference `a` to point to the new instance.  The previous instance will remain in memory but be inaccessible without any other reference to it (aka. refcount of 0) and will be cleaned up by the garbage collector when it runs.